# How to serialize strings with the Pickle module? (Python)

Tags: python, pickle

Whenever I try to do this, it gives me the error:

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

The code I used was:

```
        with open("save.pckl", 'w') as f:
        pickle.dump(name, f)
```

Does anyone know why this happens? Does Pickle just not support serializing strings? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error points to the *output* of pickle being bytes, not its *input*. In short, you must open the file in binary mode: ``open("save.pckl", 'wb')``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You open the file in the mode `'w'`. For using `pickle.dump` you should be opening it in the write binary mode `wb`:

```
with open("save.pckl", 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(name, f)
```